# How to make 3rd party javascript function that makes an asynchronous behave like an angular2 http request?

Tags: javascript, angular, http, amazon-s3

I am using the AWS-SDK to upload images to an S3 bucket. I am doing this because there is not an angular4 library for this to my knowledge. The function looks like this...

```
  public uploadImageToS3(fileInput:any, imageNumber){


    let AWSService = (<any> window).AWS;
    let file =  fileInput.target.files[0];

    let fileNameAdjusted = this.imagePathService.getRandomString()+file.name;

    AWSService.config.accessKeyId = "access key";
    AWSService.config.secretAccessKey = "secret access key";
    var s3 = new AWSService.S3({signatureVersion:'V4'});
    let bucket = new AWSService.S3({params:{Bucket:"bucket name"}, signatureVersion:'v4', ContentType: 'image/jpeg', ACL: 'public-read'});

    //I think the Key value is the name of the file to be written to S3, but not sure.
    let params =  {Key:fileNameAdjusted, Body:file};
    bucket.upload(params, function(error, res){

        console.log(imageNumber);
        console.log(res);
        console.log(error);
        if(error!=null && imageNumber==1){
          return res;
        }
        else{
          return error;
        }

      }
    );

  }
```

This function does not work because I cannot return the values from an asynchronous request like this. How can I return these values in a similar way to making http requests with pure angular functions?

When this is done with angular4 'toPromise()' is used, on the http request, and also the 'then()' function which acts as a callback handler. Is there anyway to get this behavior/functionality with the above javascript code in an angular4 app?

Comment: In asynchronous requests, you need to handle the .then() response and process it after receiving it. instead of using a return value, write the next function in your sequence inside the .then() option.

Comment: @UmashankarDas thanks for the response, but I am having trouble visualizing how that would look in code, could you possible provide a short example?

Comment: <your aysnchronous function call>
  .then(function(data) {
    // add the next function in the sequence 
    })
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // If there is any error you will catch them here
  });

Comment: Thanks. I interpret this as <your asynchronous function> as calling uploadImageToS3().then((res)=>{etc...}), but how do I return the values from uploadImageToS3() ?

Comment: If I do that now, I get a typescript error, because then must have values returned, as of now it is looked at as a void function.

Comment: You need to read about Callbacks and how to work with them. Since, that is the favored Method in javascript and nodejs for asynchronous calls.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145767/discussion-between-umashankar-das-and-dan).

Comment: Ok unfortunately I dont understand @UmashankarDas solution, I am still looking for a solution to this but will settle with duplicating code for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Modify bucket.upload to look like this.

```
bucket.upload({params, function(err, data) {
if (err) {
  return alert('There was an error uploading your photo: ', err.message);
}
// Do Successfull upload scenario
alert('Successfully uploaded photo.');
});
```

Reference : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I fail to see how this solves by issue. Correct me if I am wrong but you seem to have added error handling functionality which is not what my question is about.

Comment: In callback/async scenarios, we handle responses using 
error first handling. There is another part of the code which handles the successful upload. scenario.  Check my comment there.

Now, the problem you're facing is, since, the call is asynchronous, you are not able to send a return value. In this case, you have both scenarios or=f error and success covered. All you need to do is write the succeeding sequence for the success scenario. Instead of calling functions and handling return values from them.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that my original question does not have a solution then. I am aware that I can add code to the callback function to handle the response, but because this is an angular application, and my code has certain requirements, this will get messy, will duplicate code, and make my program harder to maintain. I have chosen to go with a workaround for now, but if anybody else has a way to return values from this function in an angular application I would be appreciative, thanks again!